# MYSQL trigger before update with iff

Tags: mysql, triggers, beforeupdate

I need to update the ESDUpdate with Today's Date whenever ESDDATE is updated.

This code is updating the ESDUpdate on ALL updates instead of just where the ESDDate is updated.

What can I do different?

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON `rhi_sap`.`dispatch_local`
FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one
BEGIN
SET NEW.dbChangeDate = NOW();

IF NEW.ESDDate IS NOT NULL Then
SET NEW.ESDUpdate = CURDATE();
End IF;

END$$
```

Comment: you need to check if the the value has actually changed? `if (new.essdate <> old.esddate) { ... }`

Comment: Well the process dictates the ESDUpdate fields is updated anytime the ESDDate is updated or verified.  So the ESDDate may not change.

Comment: Well, if ESDDate doesn't *change*, then it hasn't been *updated*, so you can't test for that in a trigger.